# How to create chunks from a stream in Servlet while uploading file through JSP

Tags: java, google-app-engine, apache-commons-fileupload

I have to upload file and have to write that file as chunks into cloud storage.

- Below is upload file code in JSP:

  ```
  <form action="/myservlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" title="File"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
  ```
- Getting the stream of uploading file in Servlet is as follows:

  ```
   ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
   FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
   FileItemStream imageItem = iter.next();
   InputStream inputStream = imageItem.openStream();
  ```

I have to create small chunks in servlet and have to upload them to cloud storage directly. Here I don't have access to local file storage since my application is running in AppEngine.

Is there a way to create chunks from the above inputstream while reading ?

Answer (score 0):

Read chunks of the desired length from the stream. Keep reading until there are no more bytes available:

```
static final int CHUNK_LENGTH = 1000000;
void readChunks(InputStream input) throws IOException {

    byte chunk[] = new byte[CHUNK_LENGTH];

    int length;
    do {
        length = IOUtils.read(input, chunk);
        if (length>0) {
            //if the total length is multiple of CHUNK_LENGTH
            //the last chunk will be empty
            doSomethingWith(chunk, length);
        }
    } while (length==CHUNK_LENGTH);         
}
```

Here `IOUtils.read` is an utility function from [commons-io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), that reads as many bytes as possible and returns the actual length read (which may be less than requested if EOF was reached)

```
   int read(final InputStream input, final byte[] buffer) throws IOException {
        int length = buffer.length;
        int remaining = length;
        while (remaining > 0) {
            final int location = length - remaining;
            final int count = input.read(buffer, location, remaining);
            if (EOF == count) { // EOF
                break;
            }
            remaining -= count;
        }
        return length - remaining;
    }
```